# How can I install Realm

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I am struggling with installation of Realm Library.

I've got failure massage like below

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:7.0.0-beta.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/7.0.0-beta/realm-gradle-plugin-7.0.0-beta.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/7.0.0-beta/realm-gradle-plugin-7.0.0-beta.pom
> Required by:
> project :
> Possible solution:
>
> - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

build.gradle(:Module)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    apply plugin: 'realm-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.7'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxkotlin:3.0.0'

    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-js-rhino:1.5.1'

}
```

build.gradle(:project)

```
buildscript {
 ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    repositories {
        google()

        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:7.0.0-beta"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {


        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Please let me know how yo fix it.

Comment: try to use with `classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.2.0"`

Comment: I got the message below
'org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be cast to org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression'